# Why are placeholders favored over Literals in psycopg2?

Tags: python, sql, psycopg2

From the [psycopg2 documentation](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html?highlight=literal#psycopg2.sql.Literal),

> class psycopg2.sql.Literal(wrapped) ... Usually you will want to include placeholders in the query and pass values as execute() arguments. If however you really really need to include a literal value in the query you can use this object.

Wouldn't `Literal`s lead to a cleaner, safer implementation with few chances for mistakes? For example, say a query contains a `%`. You'd need to make sure all `%` are escaped with another `%`.

```
>>> cur.execute("SELECT (%s % 2) = 0 AS even", (10,))       # Wrong
>>> cur.execute("SELECT (%s %% 2) = 0 AS even", (10,))      # Correct
```

then there is the sequence argument mistake

```
>>> cur.execute("INSERT INTO foo VALUES (%s)", "bar")    # Wrong
>>> cur.execute("INSERT INTO foo VALUES (%s)", ("bar"))  # Wrong
>>> cur.execute("INSERT INTO foo VALUES (%s)", ("bar",)) # Correct
>>> cur.execute("INSERT INTO foo VALUES (%s)", ["bar"])  # Correct
```

and the single quotes mistake

```
>>> cur.execute("INSERT INTO numbers VALUES ('%s')", (10,)) # Wrong
>>> cur.execute("INSERT INTO numbers VALUES (%s)", (10,))   # Correct
```

and others too.

With a `Literal` you could just use

```
>>> cur.execute(sql.SQL("SELECT ({} % 2) = 0 AS even").format(sql.Literal(10)))
```

Isn't this much better?

Comment: Maybe they just use another library that formats strings with values, and it coudln't be literals at the time when the code was written. It's not about better or worse, just about somebody implemented it in such a way, and everybody lives with it

Comment: I think the main reason is simply that it's more verbose. If you have 10 parameters you'll need to call `sql.Literal()` 10 times.

Comment: And you should note that several of the error cases don't happen when there are multiple parameters.

Comment: @Barmar if you have sequential `Literals`, you could do `map(sql.Literal, my_literals)`. And only one of the error cases (forgetting to make the parameters variable a sequence) is taken care of with multiple parameters

Comment: Only the developer knows for sure.  But from a style point of view, I'd argue:  placeholders are consistent with the DB-API spec, so they are more idiomatic and portable (ish); any examples of using `.format` and the like in relation to building SQL statements encourages inexperienced programmers to construct programs which are error-prone and vulnerable to SQL injection (it shouldn't, but it does).

Comment: Because `parameter`s get properly escaped and `sql.Literal`s are passed through as is.  To  prevent SQL injection `parameter`s are the way to go.

Comment: @snakecharmerb. The `.format` being used is a method of the `psycopg2.sql` module, not the Python string `.format`.  Reading this [sql](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html#module-psycopg2.sql) will show that it was developed to build secure dynamic queries and to get people away from using straight Python string interpolation.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Good point, well made.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Are you trying to say the result of `sql.Literal('some value)` is passed in as is? What's bad about that? The `some value` gets escaped.

Comment: My mistake I was thinking of what `sql.SQL` does while looking at `sql.Literal`. Yes it is escaped and follows the adaption rules for Python types. The primary benefit of using parameters is you can defer the passing in of the values until the `cur.execute()`. That and being able to use named placeholders/parameters to match up with data values in `dict`s.